# Error from google size content to viewport

Tags: html, css, google-pagespeed

I've tested my site in google page speed tool and in user experience section I got the following point to consider. But the issue is that I don't have any text that goes out of my page size and don't have horizontal scrolling issue. May anyone know what's the reason of this? Thanks in advance

Here's the link
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdhhandmade.com%2Fweb%2Fmp%2Fno%2F1home.html

Here's the error message:

"Size content to viewport
The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience.

The page content is 323 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 320 CSS pixels wide. The following elements fall outside the viewport:

```
The element <div class="col-sm-8 leftContainer">Moms Are Talki…r Own Question</div> falls outside the viewport.
The element <div class="col-sm-4 rightContainer">For Updates an…nver Businesse</div> falls outside the viewport.
The element <div class="row">Topics…or jobs online</div> falls outside the viewport."
```

Comment: Hey everyone, any ideas here? We'd really like to address this if possible but it's not obvious what to do

Comment: I'm still scratching my head on this one. In my CSS I make sure that the html,body,and form have a max-width of 100% and my viewport is correctly defined in the html head. Verifying the true experience a small-screen smartphone shows no horizontal scrolling necessary, and yet Google still believes I haven't correctly configured size content.